# Laravel: why invalid route action?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel/homestead project that works locally but not when I move it to HostGator.  There I'm getting

> **Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\home]**
>   App\HttpControllers\home was not found

First of all, I'm using Laravel L5 version on my working local app which doesn't require a home controller.  Maybe HostGator is running an older version of Laravel that requires one?  Just in case, I put one in there to stop the complaining.  Here it is:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller {

  public function index() {
    return view('home');
  }
}
```

Here is my /routes/web.php file:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', 'home');
Route::get('/auth0/callback', '\Auth0\Login\Auth0Controller@callback' )->name('auth0-callback');
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\Auth0IndexController@login')->name('login');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\Auth0IndexController@logout')->name('logout')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/appointments', 'AppointmentController@index');
```

But it's still complaining.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try with `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');` as route?

Comment: `Route::get('/', 'home');` should use a Controller@action instead of `home`, like all of your other routes.

Comment: What makes you think that there is another version of Laravel run on your server?

Comment: I don't really understand what Route::get('/', 'home') really mean

Comment: If you moved your application to HostGator, how could HostGator possibly be running a different version of Laravel? Your issue is that you route is not defined correctly. As others have said, you have to call a controller method such asRoute::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); which should then return a view.

Comment: @Vishal, I think it means go directly to the view called home.blade.php and skip the controller.  I learned that method from here: https://auth0.com/blog/build-a-laravel-6-app-with-authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route::get('/', 'home'); 
you have invalid declaration of the route here,

it should be like:

> Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

lets break it down:-

> **'/'  => url**
>
> **'HomeController'  => Controller to visit when the url is entered,**

**'index' => method to call inside the controller,**

name is used as a substitute for the url to make system scalable and refactoring

Comment: Thankyou Roman, Vishal, and James.  I think you all had it right.  Honestly, I'm not sure why my version did not work.  I do it that way in my local computer and it works.  There is no HomeController.php there.  Why is it needed on the remote server?  I thought maybe it was using an older version of Laravel which may have required the more verbose syntax.  But if I do php artisan --version, it shows I am using 6.14.0 on both the local and remote servers.  I hate these annoying mysteries!

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your route as below:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

Route format:

```
Route::get($uri, $callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/', 'home');
```

The second parameter, which defines the name of the controller, is 'home'. It should be 'homeController' to match the name of your controller class. It can't find a homeController class because it doesn't exist.

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

This would line up with the controller you have shown.